# Trabalhando com Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

No evento blur de um campo, eu dou um select no meu banco e trago um valor e preencho no meu html. A minha dúvida é como eu pego mais de um resultado ou um resultado específico no data do ajax.

O código abaixo funciona, mas ele só traz mensalista se o cliente for cadastrado e avulso se ele não for cadastrado. Mas além disso, quero preencher os combos com os dados dele, a cor de veículo, modelo, marca automaticamente também.

Eu tentei com session, mas no html ela so aparece se eu sair e voltar na página.

//preencher o tipo de cliente apos a placa ser digitada - Tela de entrada

```
$("#txtplaca").blur(function() {
    var url = 'consulta_tip_cli.php';
    var txtplaca = $("#txtplaca").val();    
    $.ajax ({
        url: url,
        data: {'txtplaca': txtplaca},
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {

            var msg = data;
            $("#tipo").val(msg);
        },      
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loader").css({display:"block"});
        },      
        complete: function(){
            $("#loader").css({display:"none"});
        }   
    });
});
```

meu php:

```
<?php
    include_once('status_logado.php');

    require_once('db.class.php');

    $placa = $_POST['txtplaca'];


    $sql = "SELECT idmensalista FROM `tbl_mensalista` join tbl_veiculo on IDMENSALISTA = id_mensalista ";
    $sql = $sql."where vei_placa = '$placa'";

    $objDb = new db();
    $link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();

    $resultado = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

    if($rows) {
        echo "Mensalista";
    } else  {
        echo "Avulso";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro passo é a adição do `dataType:"Json"` no seu `$.Ajax()`:

```
$("#txtplaca").blur(function() {
    var url = 'consulta_tip_cli.php';
    var txtplaca = $("#txtplaca").val();    
    $.ajax ({
        url: url,
        data: {'txtplaca': txtplaca},
        method: 'POST',
        dataType:"Json",
        success: function(data) {
            //aqui serão recebidos os dados em json da resposta do php
        },      
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loader").css({display:"block"});
        },      
        complete: function(){
            $("#loader").css({display:"none"});
        }   
    });
});
```

Agora você tem um evento que espera um `Json` como retorno, sendo assim vamos definir para o `PHP` uma resposta em `Json`, ao invés de uma `string` comum como no retorno atual, usando a função `json_encode()`:

```
include_once('status_logado.php');
require_once('db.class.php');
$placa = $_POST['txtplaca'];

$sql = "SELECT idmensalista FROM `tbl_mensalista` join tbl_veiculo on IDMENSALISTA = id_mensalista ";
$sql = $sql."where vei_placa = '$placa'";
$objDb = new db();
$link = $objDb->conecta_mysql();

$resultado = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if($rows) {
    echo json_encode($resultado);
} else  {
    echo json_encode(array("error"=>"Avulso"));
}
```

**$.Ajax()**

Dentro do parâmetro `success` do `$.Ajax()` agora estamos recebendo um array associativo como resposta, contendo toda informação que foi encontrada pela função `mysqli_query` ou uma mensagem de erro, contendo o valor `"Avulso"`.

- Supondo que sua query traga os seguintes resultados do banco de dados:

  array(
      "placa" => "abcd-1234",
      "proprietario" => "Fulano de Tal",
      "pais" => "Brasil"
  )

O parâmetro `data` da função de retorno do `success` agora contém esse array como conteúdo, sendo extraídos assim:

```
alert(data.placa)
//"abcd-1234"

alert(data["proprietario"])
//"Funlado de Tal"
```

Agora você tem acesso as informações e pode preencher o fomeulário de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Mas caso seja um usuário avulso, então ao invés desse array, virá outro, com uma chave de erro, podendo ser tratado assim:

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data.error){
        var msg = data.error;
        $("#tipo").val(msg);
    }else{
        //aqui vai ser definido os alocamentos dos dados caso a função traga os resultados do banco de dados
    }
},
```

> [Referência - **json_encode()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php)
>
> [Referência - **$.Ajax()** ver dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Fiz uma modificação : $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado) - Para eu ter um array. Quando eu imprimo o data, ele me mostra o array. Quando eu imprimo o data.idmensalista, por exemplo, ele vem: undefined. Da forma original, não funcionou :(

Comment: Mas `data["idmensalista"]` funcionou?

Comment: Não funcionou não, vou testar mais outras formas. Ele vem undefined também

Comment: @JoãoPauloSilva Coloque um `console.log(data)` no `complete` e poste aqui o que está mostrando.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui solucionar o problema! as dicas me ajudaram a chegar em um caminho e adaptar, obrigado!

```
include_once('status_logado.php');
require_once('db.class.php');

//crio uma array
$retorno = array();

$placa = $_POST['txtplaca'];

//populo
$retorno['placa'] = $placa;
echo(json_encode($retorno));
die();

$.ajax ({
        url: url,
        data: {'txtplaca': txtplaca},
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            var result = data.placa; -- acesso a posicao do array       
                alert(result); 
        },
        error: function(ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        },

        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loader").css({display:"block"});
        },

        complete: function(){
            $("#loader").css({display:"none"});     


        }



    });
```